# App getting Crashed

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I try to run my app my app crashes. It shows some error in the Log file. Following is the error displayed in the log file.

Please help in solving the error.

LOG file

```
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695): Process: com.example.er.wolfpack, PID: 8695
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.er.wolfpack/com.example.er.wolfpack.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at com.example.er.wolfpack.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
08-20 23:04:41.766: E/AndroidRuntime(8695):     ... 11 more
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView im1;
TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    im1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    tv1.setOnClickListener(this);
    im1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    startActivity(new Intent(this,Login.class));

}
}
```

Comment: what is line no 26 in MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `onCreate()` gives null means that the used ids `textView1` or `imageView1` doesn't exist in the layout `activity_login` that is in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);`. So check the layout again as you might have used wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check line 26 in mainactivity looks like one reference is null.
Probobly findViewByid return null. Probably you put there wrong id